# How to bind D and C

Tags: d

Can someone point me to a good tutorial of how to call C code from D ( and possibly to call a FORTRAN library from D)?

I've researched the topic online and keep finding incomplete examples. I would like someone to spell it out for me one time. For example, show some example bindings and explain the steps to compiling and linking them to work together.

I have both the DMD and GDC compilers on windows.

Some background: Programming isn't my main job, but I do it A LOT at work. I work with Python and Java a lot, my first language was C, and I've done some web programming too. For my next project I'd like to use D, as it seems the learning curve is much lower than C++. Also I want a compiled language, and I've never mixed two languages before.

Comment: It is unbelievable how antisocial people on SO are... Why voting to close this thread?? It is a perfectly good and polite question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look to [**Derelict.org**](https://github.com/DerelictOrg), it contains dozen of C bindings using [ffi](/questions/tagged/ffi) and [dynamic-linking](/questions/tagged/dynamic-linking) (run-time loading and delegate assignation.)

Comment: How do I link the source files from different languages into 1 executable?

Comment: Just pass the object or library files to the compiler on its command line. The compiler will pass them to the linker.

Comment: @CyberShadow, I think I'm figuring this out, so compile with the -c option for each language with it's respective compiler, then compile again with any compiler passing the *.obj files. Sound correct?

Comment: You'll probably want to use the D compiler for the final step, so it links in the D runtime. You could still use the C++ compiler or linker directly, but you'll need to specify the C and D runtime libraries to link manually.

Answer (score 0):

[Deimos](https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos) is a huge repository of bindings and wrappers of C libraries to D. I suggest you take a look at some small binding, and see how people did it.